# Generate Symmetric key in android which can be used to generate Json Web Token

Tags: android, cryptography, webcrypto-api

Our front end side has been following a method to generate symmetric key with the help of **Web cryptography api**:

```
const tempKey = await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
      {
        name: 'PBKDF2', salt: salt,
        iterations: 100000, hash: 'SHA-256'
      },
      importedPassword,
      {name: 'AES-GCM', length: 256},
      true,
      ['encrypt']
    );
```

From which i tried to interpret the 1st parameter, which is to generate **PBKDF2**:

```
SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphraseOrPin).toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), iterations, outputKeyLength);
        SecretKey secretKey = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
```

Then i totally don't understand the 3rd parameter where it tries to run **AES** algorithm with length **256** on generated `SecretKey`. How to do this in android? and why is it necessary or beneficial??

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that API, but at a guess it's used to determine the appropriate number of bits to output from the KDF. it's not actually running/using AES for anything here

the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey) for this parameter say:

> `derivedKeyAlgorithm` is an object defining the algorithm the derived key will be used for.

which seems consistent

Comment: then how do i generate "JSON Web Token" from PBKDF2 since JWT only use all standard JWS algorithms where PBKDF2 is not one of them

Comment: your updated title makes it sound like you're doing something wrong...  JWTs are normally generated server side, especially if symmetric crypto is used, and only stored by the client.  how is this related to your original title/question?

Comment: i am just reading different blogs on it, but i think your statement is not true, you can generate JWT from the client side using secret key and the point is to make sure it's not saved in the database: https://itnext.io/so-what-the-heck-is-jwt-or-json-web-token-dca8bcb719a6. I hope it's a correct statement.

Comment: yes, certainly possible (hence my saying "normally" above), it's just, in my experience, more common to see them generated server-side.  that page seems to be talking about the common case of generating and validating them server side.  client side can mostly treat JWTs as an opaque blob of text